# SystemParametersInfoA with SPI_GETMOUSE returns 0's

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mouse, getsystemmetrics

**[Go to the answer of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60241144/10750999)**

I'm trying to get my mouse speed, but when I call the function [SystemParametersInfoA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa) with parameter `SPI_GETMOUSE` it sets the target array to `{0,0,0}` which I think its not supposed to happen.

**Example code:**

```
int IntArr[3];
SystemParametersInfoA(SPI_GETMOUSE, 0, &IntArr, 0);
```

I tried changing my mouse sensitivity (from the control panel) but that didn't work either.

Does this function is supposed to return those zeros or thats my fault?

Comment: I'm assuming you really are calling `SystemParametersInfo` and not `GetSystemMetrics` as you say in the title.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Yes, you are correct. Sorry I will fix it, my bad when copy pasting :D

Comment: Is the return value of `SystemParametersInfoA()` returning FALSE? If so, what does `GetLastError()` report? And how are you printing the array exactly? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @RemyLebeau It is returning TRUE, I have it on an if statement to test aginst 0 and if its 0 I print out GetLastError, but it returns true that was why I was confused. Im printing each element of the array, but thats not the point, i tested it with debugger and memory viewer it is indeed 0.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You can literally copy and paste this and it will be exactly like mine, and see for yourself if **IntArr** has any values other than 0. im using MSVC compiler (visual studio)

Comment: It doesn't look like you're doing anything wrong. Maybe those settings aren't used by the OS any more? Or Microsoft have broken the API.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I'd bet on the second one 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa) says:

> Retrieves the two mouse threshold values and the mouse acceleration.

At first I did tought that these **two mouse threshold values** were related to my mouse cursor sensitivty.

After a deeper search in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mouse_event) for [mouse_event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mouse_event), I found out that in the [remarks section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mouse_event#remarks) it says:

> The system applies two tests to the specified relative mouse motion when applying acceleration. If the specified distance along either the x or y axis is greater than the **first mouse threshold value**, and the mouse acceleration level is not zero, the operating system **doubles the distance**. If the specified distance along either the x- or y-axis **is greater than the second mouse threshold value**, and the mouse acceleration level is equal to two, the operating system **doubles the distance that resulted from applying the first threshold test**. It is thus possible for the operating system to multiply relatively-specified mouse motion along the x- or y-axis by up to four times.

Which basically means that these 3 values that I got in the destination array ***IntArr*** wasn't anything to do with sensitivity, but rather these 2 mouse threshold values and the ["Enhance pointer precission"](https://www.howtogeek.com/321763/what-is-enhance-pointer-precision-in-windows/) which was either *0* or *1* indicating it turned *on* or *off*, **mine was disabled thats why I got all zeros.**

In order to get the mouse sensitivity you have to use [SystemParametersInfoA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa) function with the `SPI_GETMOUSESPEED` parameter as **[uiAction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa#syntax)** instead.